# PreferenceActivity causes Force close

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have a bit of an issue that I am not sure how to fix.  I have an options menu which has code like this

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.main_menu_settings:
        startActivity(new Intent(MainMenuActivity.this, BackofficePreferencesActivity.class));
        finish();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

No error happens if I comment out the line

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainMenuActivity.this, BackofficePreferencesActivity.class));
```

My preferences activity looks like this

```
public class BackofficePreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.preferences);
    }
}
```

and my layout

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="System Configuration">
    <ListPreference
       android:title="Environment"
       android:summary="Select the environment"
       android:key="@string/pref_current_environment"
       android:defaultValue="Production"
       android:entries="@array/environment_list"
       android:entryValues="@array/environment_list"
       android:dialogTitle="Select Environment" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

I even tried removing the list preference to see if the screen would load empty, but it still errors.  In eclipse, usually I can see what went wrong by looking in the LogCat tab, but for some reason nothing is being logged there anymore.  I tried rebooting my AVD and that hasn't helped.

Comment: Did you add your preference activity in the manifest file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the `Activty` in your manifest file.

Sample XML code:

```
<activity android:label="@string/sample"
        android:name=".Sample"
        android:icon="@drawable/sample">
</activity>
```